# Raspberry Pi-Docker Simulation

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, arm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a docker arm ubuntu image and simply want to test if it is running. However, seems like I cannot run the image on normal Desktop environment since the binaries are different for arm than x86_x64. Is there any way I can simulate this testing for ARM without actually getting a raspberry pi?

Comment: for arm emulation qemu might help you https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=37386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run [Raspberry Pi in a VM](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/emulate-raspberry-pi-pc/). You can download a [complete package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/) with qemu and the image for Windows. For Ubuntu, you can probably `apt-get install qemu qemu-system-arm`, download the same package, and then do the same as `run.bat` but with correct paths for Linux:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 192 -append "root=/dev/sda2"
```

Comment: Is there also an Emulator available, that uses debian jessie?

Comment: It seems like you can just download and use it but I haven't tested https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/